# Which are the preferable Payment Gateways in India for Magento?

Tags: magento2, magento-1, payment-gateway

I need a suggestion regarding implementation of **payment gateway** in magento site which can take *payment transaction from India and International* also. Please suggest some.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Indian customers , there are many like

1. [CCAvenue](https://www.ccavenue.com/)
2. [Payu](https://www.payumoney.com/)
3. [HDFC](https://www.hdfcbank.com/wholesale/corporates/large_corporates/internet_bankings/payment_gateway_services/payment_gateway_services.htm)
4. [Citrus](http://www.citruspay.com/)
5. For International , Magento default will support **Paypal**

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I am looking to go with Payu and Paypal.

Comment: What about Authorized.net?

Comment: @AhmadVaqasKhan i have no idea about `Authorized.net` , may be google will help.....